# Printing series in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a beginner in Postgres and I want to print series, say, a table contains 1 column as id with rows with data 1,2,3.

```
      id
---------------
      1
      2
      3
```

The output should be like, the value in the first row * number of times it prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, just using a self join without any auxiliary tables or sequences:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id >= t2.id
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive cte:

```
with cte(v, c) as (
   select id, id from test_table
   union all
   select v, c - 1 from cte where c > 1
)
select v from cte order by v;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()`

```
select t.id
from the_table
  cross join generate_series(1, t.id);
order by t.id;
```